# Why am i getting segmentation fault using pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am getting segmentation fault when i pass 8 computer class pointers to the Tournament class and trying to manipulate those pointers. The tournament class takes 8 Computer derived players and will call the Refree Function to Decide the number of wins of each player.
For example: Input: Tournament league(computer *Player1, *player2 ... etc)
             output: segmentation fault or doesnt print anything at all.

```
 class Computer{
        public:
            Computer();
            Computer(int number);
            int get_c_number();
            friend class Refree;
            friend class Tournament;
        public:
            string c_game;
            int c_number;
            static int no_of_win;
            string c_name;
    };
    #include "computer.h"
    Computer::Computer(){

    }
    //====computer.cpp
    int Computer::no_of_win=0;
    Computer::Computer(int number){
        c_number = number;

        for(int i=0; i<c_number; i++)
        {
            c_game.push_back('R');
        }

    }
    int Computer::get_c_number()
    {
        return c_number;
    }
    //=====example computer child class==
    #ifndef _TOOLBOX_H
    #define _TOOLBOX_H
    #include "computer.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    class Toolbox:public Computer{
        public:
            Toolbox();
            Toolbox(int number);
        private:


    };
    #endif //
    #include "toolbox.h"
    Toolbox::Toolbox(){};
    Toolbox::Toolbox(int number){
        c_number = number;

        for(int i=0; i<c_number; i++)
        {
            c_game.push_back('S');
        }


    };
    //=========tournament class==
    #define _TOURNAMENT_H
    #include "computer.h"
    #include "refree.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    class Tournament:public Computer{
        public:
            Tournament();
            Tournament(Computer *A, Computer *B, Computer *C, Computer *D, Computer *E, Computer *F, Computer *G, Computer *H);
            void decision();

        private:
            static int number_of_games;
             Computer *tournament[8];
             Computer *tournament2[4];
             Computer *tournament3[2];


    };
    #endif //_TOURNAMENT_H
    //======tournament.cpp===
    #include "tournament.h"
    int Tournament::number_of_games = 5;
    Tournament::Tournament(Computer *A, Computer *B, Computer *C, Computer *D, Computer *E, Computer *F, Computer *G, Computer *H){
        tournament[0] = A;
        tournament[1] = B;
        tournament[2] = C;
        tournament[3] = D;
        tournament[4] = E;
        tournament[5] = F;
        tournament[6] = G;
        tournament[7] = H;
    };

    void Tournament::decision(){
        Refree number1(tournament[0], tournament[1]), number2(tournament[2], tournament[3]), number3(tournament[4], tournament[5]), number4(tournament[6], tournament[7]);
        number1.decision2();
        number2.decision2();
        number3.decision2();
        number4.decision2();
       for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            if(tournament[(2*i)]->no_of_win > tournament[(2*i)+1]->no_of_win)
            {
                tournament[(2*i)]->no_of_win = 0;
                tournament[(2*i)+1]->no_of_win = 0;
                tournament2[i] = tournament[(2*i)];
            }
            else if(tournament[(2*i)]->no_of_win < tournament[(2*i)+1]->no_of_win)
            {
                tournament[(2*i)]->no_of_win = 0;
                tournament[(2*i)+1]->no_of_win = 0;
                tournament2[i] = tournament[(2*i)+1];
            }
        }


            Refree number5(tournament2[0], tournament2[1]), number6(tournament2[2], tournament2[3]);
            number5.decision2();
            number6.decision2();

        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            if(tournament2[(2*i)]->no_of_win > tournament2[(2*i)+1]->no_of_win)
            {
                tournament2[(2*i)]->no_of_win = 0;
                tournament2[(2*i)+1]->no_of_win = 0;
                tournament3[i] = tournament2[(2*i)];
            }
            else if(tournament2[(2*i)]->no_of_win < tournament2[(2*i)+1]->no_of_win)
            {
                tournament2[(2*i)]->no_of_win = 0;
                tournament2[(2*i)+1]->no_of_win = 0;
                tournament3[i] = tournament2[(2*i)+1];
            }
        }
        Refree number7(tournament3[0], tournament3[1]);
        number7.decision2();
        if(tournament3[0]->no_of_win > tournament3[1]->no_of_win)
        {
            cout<<tournament3[0]->c_name<<endl;
        }
        else if(tournament3[0]->no_of_win < tournament3[1]->no_of_win)
        {
            cout<<tournament3[1]->c_name<<endl;
        }

    };
    //============main.cpp===========
    string user_input;
        getline(cin, user_input);

        std::vector<std::string> vec;

        istringstream iss(user_input);
        copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
        istream_iterator<string>(),
        back_inserter(vec));
        Computer *players[8];
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            if(vec.at(i)=="Avalanche")
            {
                players[i] = new Avalanche(5);
                players[i]->c_name = "Avalanche";
                //cout<<"Avalanche: "<<players[i]->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="Bureaucrat")
            {
               players[i] = new Bureaucrat(5);
               players[i]->c_name = "Bureaucrat";
               // cout<<"Bureaucrat: "<<players[i]->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="Toolbox")
            {
                players[i] = new Toolbox(5);
                players[i]->c_name = "Toolbox";
               // cout<<"Toolbox: "<<players[i]->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="Crescendo")
            {
                players[i] = new Crescendo(5);
                players[i]->c_name = "Crescendo";
               // cout<<"Crescendo: "<<players[i]->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="Paperdoll")
            {
                players[i] = new Paperdoll(5);
                players[i]->c_name = "Paperdoll";
                //cout<<"Paperdoll: "<<players[i]->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="FistfullODollars")
            {
                players[i] = new Fistfullodollars(5);
                players[i]->c_name = "FistfulloDollars";
                //cout<<"FistfullOdollars: "<<players[i]->c_game<<endl;
            }
        }
        Tournament *thebigdayin = new Tournament(players[0], players[1], players[2], players[3], players[4], players[5], players[6], players[7]);
        thebigdayin->decision();
```

Comment: An sscce would be nice. See www.sscce.org

Comment: Sorry for my Dirty Pasting :( i am new to stack overflow

Comment: Whats will all of the pointers?  Can't you use vectors?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what is happening (it is hard to confirm as you have not provided a SSCCE) is after the first round some of your players have the same number of wins and it doesn't enter either the `if` or the `else if` below:

```
if(tournament[(2*i)]->no_of_win > tournament[(2*i)+1]->no_of_win)
{
    tournament[(2*i)]->no_of_win = 0;
    tournament[(2*i)+1]->no_of_win = 0;
    tournament2[i] = tournament[(2*i)];
}
else if(tournament[(2*i)]->no_of_win < tournament[(2*i)+1]->no_of_win)
{
    tournament[(2*i)]->no_of_win = 0;
    tournament[(2*i)+1]->no_of_win = 0;
    tournament2[i] = tournament[(2*i)+1];
}
```

And some of the second round players are left uninitialized. You need to decide what the tie-breaker should be.